# clang implementation of __builtin_add_overflow_p

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

I am experimenting C++ class similar to `std::integral_constant` with two primary differences:  one, it does not support `operator()` or any conversion operators.  Two, it supports non-modifying operators such as `operator+`, and my goal is to have it check the safety of these operators at compile-time.  I found [these useful builtins that GCC supports](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins).  So I can do:

```
template <typename T, T val>
class literal
{
    public:
        template <T t>
        literal<T, val + t> consteval operator+(__attribute__((unused)) const literal<T, t> &other) const
        {
            static_assert(!__builtin_add_overflow_p(val, t, static_cast<T>(0)));
            return { };
        }
};

constexpr literal<unsigned int, std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()> x, y;
x + y; // <- this gets caught by static_assert at compile-time!
```

But it turns out that clang does not support `__builtin_add_overflow_p`.  It *does* have `__builtin_add_overflow` but it is not `constexpr` and thus cannot be used at compile-time.  Is there away around this such that this code will work with clang?

Comment: Why do you want to use a builtin, which, by definition, is compiler-specific? What's wrong with checking for overflow normally?

Comment: It basically implements the overflow-checking algorithm for me.  I don't have to care about the types of the addends, or their signs, or anything really.  Compare [Mozilla's implementation](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/mfbt/CheckedInt.h#272) with/without compiler builtins - much uglier and also I'm not sure if it can be done at compile-time.

Comment: It's 3 lines instead of 1 sure. But it works everywhere and it is definitely compile-time, while that 1 line you need to have for each compiler. Plus ifdefs around, or even a different implementation file per compiler.

Comment: Also note that triggering UB is caught in a constexpr context. You can use it to your advantage an only check unsigned integers. `static_assert(std::is_signed_v<T> || (val + t >= val));` should catch all cases. Perhaps add a `static_cast<T>` around `val + t` to avoid integer promotion messing it up.